# Window size and excerpt length

Tags: jquery

I am very new about jQuery. My question is

When I resized the window size, my excerpt length is show properly, but when I expanded the window, the excerpt not change to the default length. For example, the default window size, my excerpt length is 165. When I resized the window, it changed to 105. But when I expand again. It still shows at 105. It could be 165. This is my code.

```
 function windowSize()
    {
        windowHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height();
        windowWidth = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : $(window).width();
 }
 windowSize();
 $(window).resize(function ()
 {
      windowSize();
      var str = $(".active .carousel-excerpt").text();

   if (windowWidth <= 659)
   {
      $('.active .carousel-excerpt').text(str.substring(0, 100) + '.....');
   } else if (windowWidth >= 660)
   {
      $('.active .carousel-excerpt').text();
   }
 });
```

Comment: you are modifying the value permanently when you resize to lower then 659

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 function windowSize()
    {
        windowHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height();
        windowWidth = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : $(window).width();
 }
 windowSize();
var str = $(".active .carousel-excerpt").text();
 $(window).resize(function ()
 {
      windowSize();


   if (windowWidth <= 659)
   {
      $('.active .carousel-excerpt').text(str.substring(0, 100) + '.....');
   } else if (windowWidth >= 660)
   {
      $('.active .carousel-excerpt').text(str);
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this.
[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/mifuraqaco/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
var windowHeight;
var windowWidth;
$(function(){
 windowSize();
});

$(window).resize(function ()
 {
      windowSize();

   if (windowWidth <= 450)
   {
      console.log("aaa");
   } else if (windowWidth >= 451)
   {
      console.log("bbb");
   }
 });

function windowSize()
    {
        windowHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight :   $(window).height();
        windowWidth = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : $(window).width();
 }
```

Comment: At console.log("bbb"), could i change to $('.active .carousel-excerpt').text(); ?

Answer (score 0):

You are permanently changing the string value when you reduce the screen size. To keep the original string value add another **div** with style **display:none** and keep the original string value there.

Then do the logical calculation when to show the excerpt.

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/r4nboxp1/1/

**HTML**:

```
 <div class="active">
 <div class="carousel-excerpt">
  When I resized the window size, my excerpt length is show properly, but when I expanded the window, the excerpt not change to the default length. For example, the default window size, my excerpt length is 165. When I resized the window, it changed to 105. But when I expand again. It still shows at 105. It could be 165. This is my code.
</div>
</div>
<div style="display:none" id="originalText">
</div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
var windowWidth;
 function windowSize()
    {
        windowHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height();
        windowWidth = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : $(window).width();
  }
 windowSize();
      var str = $(".active .carousel-excerpt").text();
      $("#originalText").text(str);
  $(window).resize(function ()
 {
 var originalText = $("#originalText").text();
   windowSize();
   if (windowWidth <= 400)
   {
      $('.active .carousel-excerpt').text(originalText.substring(0, 10) + '.....');
   } else if (windowWidth >= 201)
   {
      $('.active .carousel-excerpt').text(originalText);
   }
 });
```